# Meteor Cordova icons and splash screens not showing

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile, meteor

I built an app using Meteor and am currently working on getting it deployed to iOS. My problem is my app icons and splash screen are the Meteor defaults, although I defined them in my mobile.config file:

```
App.info({
  name: 'portal',
  description: 'Project Portal',
  version: '1.0.0'
});

App.icons({
  'iphone': 'public/Portal_Logo_180_180.png',
  'iphone_2x': 'public/Portal_Logo_180_180.png',
  'iphone_3x': 'public/Portal_Logo_180_180.png'
});

App.launchScreens({
  'iphone': 'public/Portal_Logo_1024x1024.png',
  'iphone_2x': 'public/Portal_Logo_1024x1024.png',
  'iphone5': 'public/Portal_Logo_1024x1024.png'
});
```

Not sure if it matters or not, but my mobile.config file is in my app's root directory. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

To add on McNulty's answer, here are specific sizes you should use for the app (you can deduce specific sizes from the filenames :) ):

```
App.icons({

    'iphone': 'resources/icons-apple/icon-60x60.png',
    'iphone_2x': 'resources/icons-apple/icon-60x60@2x.png',
    'iphone_3x': 'resources/icons-apple/icon-60x60@3x.png'
});
```

and

```
App.launchScreens({
    'iphone': 'resources/splash-apple/splash-320x480.png',
    'iphone_2x': 'resources/splash-apple/splash-320x480@2x.png',
    'iphone5': 'resources/splash-apple/splash-320x568@2x.png',
    'iphone6': 'resources/splash-apple/splash-375x667@2x.png',
    'iphone6p_portrait': 'resources/splash-apple/splash-414x736@3x.png',
    'iphone6p_landscape': 'resources/splash-apple/splash-736x414@3x.png'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I put my files inside private/media instead of public/ because it meant (I think)  they weren't included in the app cache (from memory).
2. I notice you have the same file for the different iphone sizes. Apple has quite specific guidelines for splash images and icons. Perhaps your images are not of the correct dimensions and are being disallowed. In particular 180x180 pixels (if that is what the size actually is) is way too big for your default icon.